# Sending Custom Payload using One Signal

Tags: ios, push-notification, onesignal, payload

THe client had asked to integrate OneSignal with their Android and iOS App. Earlier, they were using OpenBack for push notification. The payload which is being received in iOS and Android app in in the following format:

```
{ "aps": { "alert": { "loc-key": "WATCH_VIDEO", "loc-args": ["Mo Adham", "Simpson's theme on Two guitars"]}, "guid": "1GSIP6J" } }
```

When I look up in OneSignal dashboard, they have no option to create custom payload. I want the payload in above format from OneSignal.
Currently from dashboard, the OneSignal sends payload in this format:

```
{
    aps =     {
        alert =         {
            body = hello;
            subtitle = test;
            title = test;
        };
        sound = default;
    };
    custom =     {
        i = "db7e56d9-df72-4ec3-adbe-1cd8e1c5d327";
    };
}
```

The keys don't match in the both payloads. 
What I want to ask is does the client needs to integrate OneSignal in their backend so that they can send the payload in the specified format?

Comment: Yes. If you want to send it from your server, you can set it from your server in a specified format

Answer (score 0):

Check out their documentation on rich notifications, action buttons and customizing action buttons. Links mentioned below. If it still doesn't help, chat with their customer support.

https://onesignal.com/blog/sending-rich-notifications-in-ios10-with-onesignal/
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/action-buttons
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-action-buttons

Answer (score -1):

Try using [Create notification](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-notification)

I tested in postman

```
POST - https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications
```

Add this in header

```
Authorization: Basic FETVGER2dsaftOWQ3MS00NmQ2LTlmYmYtODkz34dasgYzkx
```

(Authorization: Basic **Your REST API Key**)

```
{
  "app_id": "d7c310b5-f2b6-4e84-8f91-c3e4b77c2904",
  "included_segments": ["Subscribed Users"], //To send all user
   "include_player_ids": ["6392d91a-b206-4b7b-a620-cd68e32c3a76","76ece62b-bcfe-468c-8a78-839aeaa8c5fa","8e0f21fa-9a5a-4ae7-a9a6-ca1f24294b86"], //To specific user using player id
  "content_available": true
}
```

REST API Key - [find here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/accounts-and-keys)